# How to protect a Raspberry Pi 4 that is powered by 5v header pin from also being plugged in to USB-c power source

Tags: power-electronics, raspberry-pi

My goal is to be able to power the RPI from either the internal pin or from the usb-c port, but protect the RPI board in case both sources are connected at the same time.

I’m powering a RPI 4 via the 5v pins directly on the board. If the pi is also accidentally plugged in to a usb-c cable, both sources would be effectively connected in parallel, which will fry the board.

Is there a circuit that can detect that there is already voltage coming in from the 5v pin, and if so, block the internal power source from supplying voltage to the pin?

Comment: For Rpi W (I think similar for other Rpi's), the USB power is isolated/protected from the External power by a Zener diode.  See the following schematic from Rpi W datasheet (more details in Chapter 2): https://imgur.com/a/WIA7VSy.

Comment: @ tlfong01 D1 (MBR120VLSFT1G) is: DIODE SCHOTTKY 20V 1A SOD123FL

Comment: @Rodo: Ah, my apologies. It is a Schottky. MBR120VLSFT1G ***Schottky Power Rectifier***, Surface Mount 1.0 A, 20 V, SOD-123 Packag - OnSemi
https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mbr120vlsft1-d.pdf